# Publishing Android Kotlin library along with source code

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to publish a library with source code.

My library project structure

```
:library:
└── src
    └── main
        └── kotlin
            └── <package>
                └── MyLibrary.kt
```

gradle.kts

```
plugins {
   ...
   id("maven-publish")
}

android {
   ...
   // sourceSets{} block is not present as new AGP automatically recognises "src/main/kotlin" as kotlin source
   ...
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            register<MavenPublication>("release") {
                groupId = mGroupId
                artifactId = mArtifactId
                version = mVersion

                from(components["release"])
                artifact(tasks.getByName("androidReleaseSourcesJar"))
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("androidReleaseSourcesJar", Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")

    // Can't refer to `kotlin.srcDirs` but `java.srcDirs` works fine
    from(android.sourceSets["release"].kotlin.srcDirs)
}
```

I'm getting error at line

```
from(android.sourceSets["release"].kotlin.srcDirs)
```

How do I get the reference to all the sourceSet(kotlin + java), if not then only kotlin?

AGP Version: 7.1.0-beta01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I figured out was

```
kotlin.sourceSets["main"].kotlin.srcDirs
```

for publishing kotlin source. If you need to do combination of multiple source for a variant, you will need to do something like

```
kotlin.sourceSets["main"].kotlin.srcDirs + kotlin.sourceSets["debug"].kotlin.srcDirs
```

final output

```
tasks.register("androidReleaseSourcesJar", Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(kotlin.sourceSets["main"].kotlin.srcDirs)
}
```

Verified on AGP:7.1.0-beta01 & Gradle: 7.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the Gradle Kotlin DSL. But we did the following workaround to access the Kotlin source directories:

```
val kotlinSrcDirs = (android.sourceSets["release"].kotlin.srcDirs() as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet).srcDirs
```

Comment: Sorry for not updating here. Here is what I ended up doing
`kotlin.sourceSets["main"].kotlin.srcDirs`

Comment: Thank you. It works. That's much better!